# cURL command works in git bash but not in cmd and powershell

Tags: powershell, api, curl, cmd, git-bash

The folowing command works in git bash but not in cmd and powershell

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5678/api/findgen -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"a": "Val 1","b": "Val 2","c": "Val 3","d": "Val 4"}' -o "file.json"
```

I get error in cmd such as -

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
>
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Val 1,b
>
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Val 2,c
>
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Val 3,d
>
> curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 6

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the error message:

> Invoke-WebRequest  Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type:
>   application/json" value of type "System.String" to type 
>   "System.Collections.IDictionary".

In PowerShell, `curl` is an alias for the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet. As the error points it out, the `Header` parameter must be a IDictionary, not a string. This is how it looks like in PowerShell:

`@{"Content-Type"= "application/json"}`

Some parameters are also different. This is how I would script the request:

```
Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Uri "http://localhost:5678/api/findgen" `
    -Headers @{"Content-Type"= "application/json"} `
    -Body '{"a": "Val 1","b": "Val 2","c": "Val 3","d": "Val 4"}' `
    -OutFile "file.json" `
    -Method Post
```

Comment: The error message this answer refers to doesn't exist in the question. The question shows error messages from the real curl. This is highly confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I see those "`Could not resolve host`" only with `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe` on Windows 10 (build 17063 or later), because of the way the [Windows `curl.exe` native program](http://get-cmd.com/?p=5181) interprets single and double quotes.

If you inverse/escape those quotes, it does work (on CMD)

```
C:\Windows\System32\curl -X POST http://localhost:5678/api/findgen \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    ^^^
     double-quotes
  -d "{\"a\": \"Val 1\",\"b\": \"Val 2\",\"c\": \"Val 3\",\"d\": \"Val 4\"}" -o "file.json"
     ^^^
     double quotes outside, escaped double-quotes inside: valid JSON
```

This is similar to "[How do I POST JSON with Curl?](https://reqbin.com/req/c-dwjszac0/curl-post-json-example)"

On Powershell, I had to escape double quotes (backtick, as commented), and escape `{}`: `{{}}`

```
PS D:\> C:\Windows\System32\curl -X POST https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json `
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" `
   -d "{{`"login`":`"my_login`",`"password`":`"my_password`"}}"
```

Alternatively:

```
PS D:\> C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -X POST https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json `
>>    -H "Content-Type: application/json" `
>>    -d '{{""login"":""my_login"",""password"":""my_password""}}'
{"success":"true"}
```

From Steven's post:

```
PS D:\> C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" `
    -d '{""north"": ""each south""}' https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
{"success":"true"}
```

Using `curl.exe` alone means using the MingW Git for Windows curl.exe

```
PS D:\> curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" `
>>     -d '{""north"": ""each south""}' https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: each
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 6:
south} https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
```

You therefore need to escape curly brackets, and remove any space:

```
PS D:\> curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" `
>>     -d '{{"north":"each south"}}' https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
{"success":"true"}
```

Or, using spaces, with single quotes:

```
PS D:\> curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" `
>>     -d '{\"north\": \"each south\"}' https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
{"success":"true"}
```

---

On CMD If you want to keep those quotes unchanged, used the [mingw](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) `curl.exe` packaged with [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), at least on CMD.

```
C:\path\to\git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe -X POST http://localhost:5678/api/findgen \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"a": "Val 1","b": "Val 2","c": "Val 3","d": "Val 4"}' -o "file.json"
     ^^^
     You can keep the quotes as-is
```

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101566/curl-command-works-in-git-bash-but-not-in-cmd-and-powershell/66836733#comment118144965_59101566), in a Powershell session, `curl` itself is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`.

I tested it with:

```
PS D:\> Get-Alias -Name curl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest


PS D:\> curl -uri https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json `
>>     -Method 'POST' -ContentType "application/json" `
>>     -Body "{""login"":""my_login"",""password"":""my_password""}"


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"success":"true"}

RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
                    cf-request-id: 0917a97460000053c82aa69000000001
                    Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/bea...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [CF-Cache-Status, DYNAMIC], [cf-request-id, 0917a97460000053c82aa69000000001], [Expect-CT, max-age=604800,
                    report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : System.__ComObject
RawContentLength  : 19
```

Comment: @StevenPenny I have edited the first example (and tested it, in a Powershell session)

Comment: @StevenPenny I have edited my answer to make your deleted answer example work. (tested in a PowerShell session)

Comment: @StevenPenny Note the single `{...}` curly brackets with that kind of syntax (no need for `{{...}}`)

Comment: @StevenPenny I just copy/pasted the last edit in a PowerShell session, starting with `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe` (to be sure to use the "correct" `curl`): I get `{"success":"true"}`. `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` 5      1      19041  610 on Windows 10 20H2

Comment: @StevenPenny OK: space added. Still success (but using -X POST and -H for JSON header). And using `{...}`, not `{{...}}`

Comment: @StevenPenny I have fixed your example, using `curl.exe` (the curl 7.75.0 for Windows or the one from Git, not the `Windows\System32` one)

Comment: I confirmed with `--trace-ascii` that this finally produces a correct request. However since final edit was merely a copy of another answer, I will have to consider that regarding bounty

Answer (score 0):

So here is the adapted syntax as a one liner :

```
curl.exe "-X" "POST" "https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json" `
"-H" "Content-Type: application/json" `
"-d" '{\"a\": \"Val 1\",\"b\": \"Val 2\",\"c\": \"Val 3\",\"d\": \"Val 4\"}' `
"-o" "file.json"
```

And a way a little more friendly for JSON :

```
curl.exe "-X" "POST" "https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json" `
"-H" "Content-Type: application/json" `
"-d" (@{a='Val 1';b='val 2';c='Val 3';d='Val 4'} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress) `
"-o" "file.json"
```

Comment: I confirmed with `--trace-ascii` that this produces correct request. If no better answers then this will get bounty - thanks

Comment: @StevenPenny Did you think we should add the pure CMD one ? (`curl.exe "-X" "POST" "https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json" "-H" "Content-Type: application/json" "-d" "{""a"": ""Val 1"",""b"": ""Val 2"",""c"": ""Val 3"",""d"": ""Val 4""}" "-o" "file.json"`)

Comment: personally CMD is old, so I would leave that out