# curl command doesn't work properly in command prompt

Tags: windows, api, pdf, curl, cmd

I'm trying to use a certain API at [this site](https://htmlpdfapi.com/documentation/usage) by curl.
I'm trying the example snippet written in the page on Command Prompt, but cmd returns error below:

```
curl -H 'Authentication: Token myToken' \

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Token
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: myToken'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \

-d 'html=<h1>HTML PDF API is cool!</h1>' \

The system cannot find the file specified.

'https://htmlpdfapi.com/api/v1/pdf' > result.pdf

''https:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I searched for the usage of curl and Documentation of this API, but I couldn't solve.
Being very new to using API, using curl, and HTTP, I don't even know how to divide my problem and how to search the solution.

Any information would be appreciated.

### progression

I found that

- Windows version of curl is a bit different from Unix version of curl which is shown in the examples at the API site.
- I tried the same command on WSL Ubuntu, it worked.

I'm thinking that Windows is a bit uncomfortable and taking effort in doing engineering things, because many engineering tools out there are supposed to be used in Linux of Mac.

Comment: I guess you're wrongly using `\ ` as a command parts line separator. It's `^` on the Windows `cmd.exe` CLI for that purpose.  Also, you should not  add an answer that is a part of the question...

Comment: Check also [these question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59101566/3641635) about curl syntax.

Comment: The issue is not `curl.exe`. The  issue is the different syntax of Windows command processor in comparison to Linux shell interpreters. The Linux shell interpreters support multiple variants of quoting of argument strings with different interpretation depending on the used quotes. The Windows command processor supports only `"` to quote an argument string containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` to get everything inside the double quoted argument string interpreted as literal characters with the exception of `%` and of `!` with delayed expansion currently enabled.

Comment: ``\`` at end of a line is interpreted by Linux shell interpreters as escape for the line ending. That means the strings on next line are appended to the command line currently parsed by the shell interpreter. That is also possible on Windows, but the escape character is `^` which must be at end of the line to get the strings on next line interpreted as part of the current command line. I suggest to make it simple and write just one command line with: `curl.exe -H "Authentication: Token myToken" -d "html=<h1>HTML PDF API is cool!</h1>" "https://htmlpdfapi.com/api/v1/pdf" > result.pdf`

Comment: In my opinion __Effectiva studio d.o.o.__ should extend the webpage [HTML PDF API Usage](https://htmlpdfapi.com/documentation/usage) and post for each Linux/Mac usage example also the Windows usage example. That would be pretty easy for the examples on this page as all `'` need to be just replaced by `"` and all ``\`` by `^` to have all examples in valid syntax for the Windows command processor.

Answer (score 0):

I found that

- Windows version of curl seems a bit different from Unix version of curl which is shown in the examples at the API site.
- I tried the same command on WSL Ubuntu, and it worked.

I'm thinking that Windows is a bit uncomfortable and taking effort in doing engineering things, because many engineering tools out there are supposed to be used in Linux or Mac.

It ended up taking a bit different way as I expected, I would like to close this question here for the present, as at least I can use this API now.

Any discussion about this question would still be welcomed.